# What does the following represent?

Tags: rebus

What does the following represent?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This represents…

> Division with zero

> Dividing zero by a nonzero number ($\frac {0}{K}$) is "OK" because it evaluates to 0. However, dividing by zero ($\frac{N}{0}$) is a "NO" because it is undefined.